# Why function `load` not works in `lapply` but works in `for` loops?

Tags: r, load, apply

I am trying to load a sequence of files into a list in R. Here below is example and the code I used.

```
## data
val <- c(1:5)
save(val, file='test1.rda')
val <- c(6:10)
save(val, file='test2.rda')

## file names
files = paste0('test',c(1:2), '.rda')
# "test1.rda" "test2.rda"

## use apply to load data into a list 
res <- lapply(files, function(x) load(x))
res
# [[1]]
# [1] "val" # ??? supposed to be 1,2,3,4,5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "val" # ??? supposed to be 6,7,8,9,10


## use for loops to load data
for (i in c(1:2)){
  load(files[i])
}
# data sets are loaded as expected
```

I cannot see why the `apply + load` function is not returning the correct list. I appreciate it if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: `load()` returns the names of the objects it creates.  Both of your files created an object named `val`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` function is not a good way to assign saved R objects because it loads the object directly in your environment (as you did in your for loop, without assigning a new named object)

`saveRDS` and `readRDS` would serve you to assign a saved file to a new object in your environment;

```
val <- c(1:5)
saveRDS(val, file='test1.rds')
val <- c(6:10)
saveRDS(val, file='test2.rds')

files = paste0('test',c(1:2), '.rds')

res <- lapply(files, function(x) readRDS(x))
res
```

**output;**

```
1. 1 2 3 4 5
2. 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Your advice is good, but `load()` is even worse than you think:  it's not into the working environment, it's into the calling environment, which disappears when `lapply()` finishes.

Answer (score 6):

Bottom line up front: `load` loads data into the calling environment, and that is very different when run from a `for` loop and from `lapply`. You can override this to force into *which* environment the data is loaded.

If you read `?load`, you'll see the `envir=` argument:

```
Usage:

     load(file, envir = parent.frame(), verbose = FALSE)
     
Arguments:

    file: a (readable binary-mode) connection or a character string
          giving the name of the file to load (when tilde expansion is
          done).

   envir: the environment where the data should be loaded.

 verbose: should item names be printed during loading?
```

Since the default is `parent.frame()`, that means it is being loaded into the environment defined within `lapply`, not the global environment.

Demonstration:

```r
for (i in 1:2) { print(environment()); }
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ign <- lapply(1:2, function(ign) print(environment()))
# [[1]]
# <environment: 0x000000006f54b838>                # not R_GlobalEnv, aka .GlobalEnv
# [[2]]
# <environment: 0x000000006f54de58>
```

Also, since

```
Value:

     A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.
```

this means that `res <- lapply(files, load)` will always only return a `character` vector, not the values itself.

While I agree with Samet Sökel's premise that `readRDS` provides a more *functional* interface (meaning: it returns something, it doesn't operate solely on side-effect), the workaround is not too difficult:

1. Load into the global environment:

   ```r
   res <- lapply(files, load, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   ```

   This will return the *name* of all variables loaded into `res`, and all data appearing in the global environment.
2. Load into a user-defined environment:

   ```r
   e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
   res <- lapply(files, load, envir = e)
   # all data is now in 'e'
   ```

   `res` will also contains just the names, but this is a little bit closer to a *functional* interface in that the data is going into a very specific place you define.

   Don't dismiss this quickly: if you ever choose to "productionize" your code that loads all of the `.rda` files, it might be nice for it to load the data into an environment other than `.GlobalEnv`. For one, loading while inside a function and putting the data in global is really bad practice, and it might not always work smoothly for your function. Okay, it's just "one", side-effect in a production-type function/package is a bad thing (imo): it often breaks reproducibility, it can really mess with users who happen to have same-named variables in *their* environment ... and overwriting them is an irreversible operation that can quickly lead to anger and lost productivity. Side-effect is also very difficult to troubleshoot when something goes wrong.

Comment: just 16 minutes after the question was asked. I am a huge fan of you.